# Dynamic SQL in stored procedure - concatenate with multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a view with columns being concatenated to produce the rows for an import.

Here is the statement I have :

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
declare @SQL as varchar(4000)
        --@CD as date

--set @CD = convert(varchar(30), cast(getdate() as date), 110)


    -- Insert statements for procedure here
set @SQL = 'CREATE VIEW vw_GCS_Export
    As
    select division, [primary image id],[Item Number], [Brand Name],[Marketing Description],
    [Colours]as Colors,[Live Date],[Sample Type],substring([FileName],charindex('+ CHAR(39) + '_' + CHAR(39) +',[FileName],1)+1,CHARINDEX('+ CHAR(39) + '.' + CHAR(39) +',[FileName],1)-5) as BatchID,
    '+ CHAR(39) + '670' + CHAR(39) +' as Status, [Primary image ID] + '+ CHAR(39) + '_P' + CHAR(39) +' as [Shot Name],
    Cast(Null as varchar(50))as [Swatch/Variation],Cast(Null as varchar(50))as [Alternate Shot],[UserName],''' + CAST(convert(date,Sysdatetime(),110)as varchar(10)) + ''' as [Import Date],
    Cast(Null as varchar(50))as [Return Instructions],Cast(Null as varchar(50))as [Rush Request], DATEADD(WEEKDAY,-5,[live date]) as [ImageDeliveryDate],
    '+ CHAR(39) + 'Division '+ CHAR(39) + '+ [division] +'+ CHAR(39) + ' * ' + CHAR(39) +' + [UserName] as JobName
    from Sheet1$'


EXEC (@SQL)
select * from vw_GCS_Export

END
```

When I execute the stored procedure I get an error:

> Error converting data type varchar to float.

Do I need to define the column as `nvarchar(50)` or something similar using cast?

Comment: I'm guessing it is your concatenation of either `[Primary image ID] + ''_P''` or `''Division'' + [division] + '' * '' + [UserName]`. I would wrap the variables you're pulling from the spreadsheet in `CAST` or `CONVERT` and that should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

nThere is a lot of information missing in this question, such as the data types of the columns in [Sheet1$]. However, I can give you a general explanation. You will get this error any time an expression tries to concatenate a float value with a string value. You might expect that the automatic conversion would be to convert the float to a string and then concatenate, but in actuality what happens is that MSSQL tries to convert the string to a numeric value and then add it to the float. As Love2Learn said, you need to explicitly cast/convert the numeric values to strings, e.g.

```
cast([Primary image ID] as varchar(max)) + '_P' as [Shot Name]
'Division '+ cast([division] as varchar(max)) +' * ' + [UserName] as JobName
```

Comment: That is correct.  The field [division] is a float data type.  I did a convert on that field and the statement works.  What I learned is that a single cast or convert function cannot be applied to multiple different data types simultaneously.  Please keep in mind that I am self taught SQL programmer, and I use that term loosely, so I am learning fun and exciting stuff everyday just by accident.

Comment: I am self-taught as well. The SQL Server documentation is very high quality. You can learn almost everything you need from there.